# Method from a category throws an exception after upgrade to Xcode 4.2/iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a category that extends `NSMutableArray` with a shuffle method. The category is declared and implemented in an `.h` file, which is included by the `.pch` file. Worked fine on iOS 3.xx and 4.xx.
I installed Xcode 4.2 yesterday. Recompiled app with the base SDK set to 5.0 and the deployment target to 3.2 throws `-[__NSArrayM shuffle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...`

I tried iPhone 5.0 simulator, iPad 5.0 simulator, iPhone 4G with iOS 5 - no difference.

Now, if I move the declaration/implementation to `.m` where the class that sends the `shuffle` message is implemented the app runs fine.
The original `.h` does get imported - if I just copy the code from the original `.h` to `.m` the compiler complains about duplicate declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade to Xcode 4.2 caused the compiler to change from GCC to Apple LLVM. And LLVM does not like implementation in .pch. Extracting the implementation to an .m file, importing the original .h directly, compiling with GCC all solve the problem.

Comment: Finally, some info about the problem I'm having. But I tried this answer and it still didn't work! Any idea? I'm about to pull my hair out...

Comment: I ended up keeping my implementation in the pch and creating an NSOBject with public methods. works for now